# Excel solver in Python for optimization problem

Tags: python, excel, solver

I just started to use python so I still do not know very well how to implement things.
I would like to use the solver tool available in Excel in python (of course without the help of Excel). To make it super easy let's say I am solving a simple equation

10+4/a+a=b

so using the Excel solver if I put for b a value of 16, the solver will find the optimum a value.
Is there a way to do the same easily also with python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an equation solver – see e.g. https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/10-Symbolic-Math/10.06-Solving-Equations/

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot. Thank you very much! One more question. This was an easy calculation but do you think that this approach works well also if the equation that need to be solved is quite complex? Or is better to use another approach?

Comment: I tried with a more complex equation and it always appears "No algorithms are implemented to solve equation"!!!

Comment: You may need something more powerful like Maxima. (Not Python though.)

Comment: But the strange thing is that the Excel solver is able to find a solution. That is why I thought Python was able to

Comment: What is the complex equation in particular?

Comment: For example this is one of the equation:                                                         
     X =-0,00015*(RADQ(A)-0,339)^(-1,49)*(864,95*RADQ(A)-197). If I use the Excel solver and I put the value of the objective X=-0,8 I get A=0.2. If I do it with Python I do not have any solution. I do not know if the problem is that Python try to identify the right solution and Excel try only to optimize the function giving the most near value.

Comment: RADQ() is SQRT(), yeah?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Another point can also be the fact that my equation is non linear? To solve it in Excel I am using GRG non linear solver. Is sympy solver only for linear equation?

Comment: I don't know about the full capabilities of Sympy, but are you looking for an exact solution or a numerical one?

Comment: If there is not an exact solution a numerical one is also fine. I cannot understand why Excel is able to do it easily, while in Python seems that there is no solution

Comment: Of course there is a solution, now that we know what you're looking for. As to why Excel can do it "easily", have you considered how many man-hours have gone into it, and that you also have to pay for it? :)

Comment: ahahaha yes, sure. You are right. But can you suggest me something else to try?

Comment: You should probably look into Scipy's solving/minimization functions next: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.5.2/reference/optimize.html

Comment: Yes, I did it. Now I used nsolve instead of solve. The problem is that I need to put as starting point a value really close to the one I want to obtain